# MacBook Pro 9.1 (mid 2012) enable GPU switching in Debian 9.3

Tags: debian, nvidia, macintosh, gpu, i915

I work in deep learning projects and I need to run my MBP on Linux for running demos.

I have installed Debian Linux 9.3 and everything is fine, except for the GPU which is always on. I cannot find a way to turn it off and switch to integrated Intel video adapter when not needed.

I am running on latest release of nvidia-driver (375.82) and I cannot use Nouveau due to the need of CUDA.

I wish to have the same automatic switching like in OS X, but a manual switch would be fine.

- I have tried already *bumblebee*, but the X server does not start and
  halt on an error "no _DSM call".
- I have tried [gpu-switch](https://github.com/0xbb/gpu-switch) too, but when I reboot on integrated
  Intel card I get a "Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting
  0xaa55, got 0xffff" error.

Here some details that might help.

```
sudo lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
```